# creating a backward list using recursive data type in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to create a backward list using Haskell's recursive types

```
data RevList a = Snoc a (RevList a) | Lin
    deriving Show 

mkrevlst [] = Lin
mkrevlst (x:xs) = mkrevlst xs Snoc x
```

When I do `> mkrevlst [1,2,3]` ,the output I am expecting is : `((Lin Snoc 3) Snoc 2) Snoc 1`

When I run this I get an error. I am new to Haskell & I am not able to make out where is mistake is. 
Where am I going wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Please state what exact error you get. "I get an error" is not a description of an error.

Comment: It would be more idiomatic to define Revlist like this `data RevList a = Snoc (RevList a) a | Lin`. The original definition is a Cons list (i.e. a normal list without syntactic sugar) that relies on a "smart constructor" `mrevlist` to make it notionally a Snoc list.

Comment: @n.m , the error I am getting is a type error.

@stephen tetley, yes you are right, it should be data RevList a = Snoc (RevList a) a | Lin , but I am still trying to figure out how to write the function to display the list properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what this line was supposed to be, but it doesn't make sense as is:

```
mkrevlst (x:xs) = mkrevlst xs Snoc x
```

The expression `mkrevlist xs` presumably has type `RevList a`, since the base case above returns `Lin`. Applying this to two more arguments will indeed result in a type error.

It *looks* like you're expecting `Snoc` to be used infix, is that correct? In Haskell, identifiers made of alphanumeric characters are prefix, unless surrounded by backticks, e.g. `` mkrevlist xs `Snoc` x ``. Identifiers made of symbols are infix, unless surrounded in parentheses, and infix data constructors specifically must start with a colon. So you could also define your data type like this:

```
data RevList a = a :| (RevList a) | Lin
    deriving Show
```

Also, note that even if you do use `Snoc` infix, the order of its arguments are still backwards from how you're using it in `mkrevlist`.

Comment: When I modified it to this:

`data RevList a = Lin | RevList a :| a 
    deriving Show` 

`mkrevlst [] = Lin`
`mkrevlst (x:xs) = mkrevlst xs :| xs`

I am getting the output as `((Lin :| []) :| [3]) :| [2,3]`
This is close to what I wanted to get.
But what is this symbol `:|` which you have mentioned? If I replace that symbol with the word `Snoc`, it doesn't work.

Comment: @BharatKrishna: It's a data constructor, just like `Snoc`. The only difference is that `:|` is operator style so it can be written infix directly, and appears that way in the default `Show` instance. If you want to use `Snoc` infix, surround it with backticks like in my answer, but it won't appear that way in the output of `show`.

Comment: thanks! I was really confused between the infix & prefix representations. I was trying to use Snoc as infix without backricks and then really got confused in writing the function to populate the list. Now it is working.

Comment: @BharatKrishna: Fair enough! This is a case where the most helpful thing can be to simply read the formal specification for the language syntax. But as a quick guide: alphanumeric is prefix, symbols are infix; identifiers beginning with an uppercase letter or `:` are types/constructors/classes/etc., identifiers beginning with a lowercase letter or any other symbol are terms/type variables/etc.

Answer (score 3):

A list of things is either empty or a thing followed by a list of things. This is exactly what you have as your definition of RevList. It is isomorphic to a normal list, not reversed at all. A real reversed list is defined symmetrically to a normal list.

> A list of thing is either empty or a
>   thing followed by a list of things.

Symmetrically,

> A reversed-list of things is either empty or a
>   reversed-list of things followed by a
>   thing.

Rewrite this in Haskell, using an infix data constructor as in camccann's answer, and you will get what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this:

```
mkrevlst [] = Lin
mkrevlst (x:xs) = Snoc x (mkrevlst xs)
```

Snoc constructor need 2 parameters where as you were passing only one i.e x
It will solve the error but it wont solve your problem of creating a output like:

```
((Lin Snoc 3) Snoc 2) Snoc 1
```

For this you need to modify your data structure