# Explanation of the infix data constructor operator

Tags: haskell

I was reading this interesting blog post called [Parse, don't validate](https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2019/11/05/parse-don-t-validate/) and it includes this:

> To do this, we need a type that represents non-empty lists. Fortunately, the existing NonEmpty type from Data.List.NonEmpty is exactly that. It has the following definition:
>
> ```
> data NonEmpty a = a :| [a]
> ```
>
> Note that NonEmpty a is really just a tuple of an a and an ordinary, possibly-empty [a]. This conveniently models a non-empty list by storing the first element of the list separately from the list’s tail: even if the [a] component is [], the a component must always be present.

The only place I could find anything about `:|` was in the comments to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420606/creating-a-backward-list-using-recursive-data-type-in-haskell), which meant I need to have some understanding of that question/discussion and parse the formatting.

Is there any documentation for this (my searches bore no fruit) and is there a simple explanation of its use? I don't get it, as I only sometimes dip my toe in the water with Haskell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Full name of type is `Data.List.NonEmpty`.

You can find details [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html)

There is site https://hoogle.haskell.org/ which is good starting point in searching functions, types, etc. in haskell libraries.

**EDIT**: If you confuse with what `:|` mean then here some explanation.

In haskell you can define custom operators like `.`, `$`, `<*>`. Same way you can create infix constructor with custom "names".

So you can define one yourself:

```
data MyType = Integer :++ Integer
```

and use them as

```
someVal :: MyType
someVal = 1 :++ 2
```

or

```
foo :: MyType -> Integer
foo (a :++ b) = a
```

Note that it have to start with `:` (Thanks to @Ben)

Comment: Hi talex. I'm asking about `:|` not `NonEmpty`. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You interested in `:|` specifically or want to learn about infix constructors in general?

Comment: :| specifically. For instance, I've no idea how to rewrite that constructor without that operator, if that helps show my ignorance.

Comment: What exactly you want to know about it? I thought all information you need you can learn from its definition `data NonEmpty a = a :| [a]`.

Comment: I guess that's because you understand it :) If I look up "haskell data constructor" and go through articles explaining them, I won't find any examples with `:|` in there, because I've been through quite a few. I just don't get what it's doing.

Comment: Oh. I got it. `:|` doesn't have special meaning here. You can replace it with `:::`, `|:+` or any other combination of punctuation character. It is like constructor name but consists of punctuation characters instead of letters.

Comment: @talex Yeah, you kinda just have to know that you can define infix data constructors using symbols. Everybody sees the example of `:` for lists, but lists have other dedicated syntax so there's nothing to tell you that `:` isn't special. The Haskell Report does spell this out reasonably clearly (https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch2.html#x7-180002.4), but people don't learn the language from that, so if your learning material doesn't point out infix constructors then you just don't know about them.

Comment: @talex Btw it can't be any combination of punctuation characters. Much like normal identifiers are split into "constructors" beginning with an upper-case letter and "variables" beginning with a lower-case letter (or underscore), symbolic constructors must be distinguished by beginning with a `:`. (Basically: colons are "upper case")

Comment: @Ben thanks, didn't know that. Never used that feature myself.

Comment: *Now* I get it! Thanks talex, and everyone.

Answer (score 6):

The `data` declaration *defines* `:|`, rather than *using* a predefined `:|` operator.

Consider the oft-used example of how `[]` is defined in (pseudo) Haskell:

```
data [] a = [] | (:) a ([] a)  -- data [a] = [] | a : [a]
```

Here, `:` is being defined as the operator that creates a list given an element of type `a` and another list of type `[a]`.

Any type can create an infix constructor, just as you can define infix operators. The difference between an infix constructor and an infix operator is that the constructor can, and must, begin with a `:`. (`(:)` itself is the trivial example of one, starting with and consisting *only* of a `:`.)

You can also define type-level infix constructors. For example,

```
type f :+: g = Either f g
```

Answer (score 4):

`:|` is just the name of the constructor. It’s essentially the same as doing this:

```hs
data NonEmpty2 a = (:|) a [a]
```

Or this:

```hs
data NonEmpty3 a = TheNonEmptyConstructor a [a]

(:|) = TheNonEmptyConstructor
```

The constructor name must begin with a colon in order to be used as an infix operator, but otherwise it’s just a normal constructor, except that you can also use it as an operator.

Now, why would someone need this? Really, it’s just because `1 :| [2,3,4]` is much nicer to read and write than `ConstructorName 1 [2,3,4]`!

Comment: Ah, the laziness of programmers. I should've known! :) Thanks.

Comment: @iain I wouldn’t call it laziness as such. Haskell programmers very often define functions (and less often constructors and data types) as operators, simply because it works better for that particular usecase. A great example is the monadic bind operator `>>=`: something like `m >>= func1 >>= func2 >>= func3` is a _lot_ easier to read than `bind (bind (bind m func1) func2) func3`. Another good example is the [TidalCycles](https://tidalcycles.org/index.php/Welcome) library, which allows musical composition in Haskell by using operators to put pieces of music together.